# Finding dates in ListObject header - Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to create a dynamic table which will contain data for hours. The first few columns will be Names, Projects, Roles etc then will have dates (set 1 week apart). The information for this table will be autopopulated from another sheet. I'm having trouble with a function which will:
1 - read a date from another sheet
2 - look into the header row of the table to determine if the date exists. The condition should execute code based off the following criteria:

> If the date exists then, return the column position of the date so that the rows can be populated with data.

> If the date does not exist then find the position of the week before and the week after and insert a new column with the header of the date. Then return the column position of the date so that the rows can be populated with data.

In my code so far I have tried to declare the input date as a variant, long, date and double but have had no luck.
I've been trying the Application.Match function but am not having much luck. I have also tried to assign an array which has a date class to to get the match function to work. I have a feeling that I am not referencing the ListObject correctly.

[An example of the type of table in question. If for example I was searching for 05/04/21 and Column G did not exist, then the function should be able to recognise this and insert a column between 29/03/21 and 12/04/21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJhVG.png)

Anyone have some tips?

Comment: In a **Table** the headers will be strings.  Application.Match sees strings and numbers as different.  Use the VBA Format function to turn the date you are searching for into a string.

Comment: You are right. I was hoping to try and avoid this as I thought it would cause issues between forcing the input date to a string but seems as though it can work. I've had some extra help to write the functions which converts the strings to compare the dates then forces the date to be inserted where I need it. Thanks for the input @RonRosenfeld !

Comment: Yes, there are potential issues when treating dates as strings. But since Table column headers **must** be strings, you will need to deal with that layer of complexity.